# Arr.map returns null instead of removing object completely?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove each user that does not have a firstName and lastName.

This is the object:

```
users = [{firstName: "john", lastName: "smith"}, {firstName: "", lastName: ""}]
```

This is my code:

```js
let users = this.users.map(user => {
        if (user.firstName !== '' && user.lastName !== '') {
          return user
        }
})
```

It does remove the empty ones, but it replaces it with null, and I want to completely remove it and not display null instead of the object.

What I get when I log it the mapped array: `[{firstName: "john", lastName: "smith"}, null]`

Comment: well map does not remove indexes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `filter`, not a `map`, a `map` simply applies some transformation on the elements, `filter`, however, is suitable for removing/keeping elements based on certain conditions:

```js
var users = [{firstName: "john", lastName: "smith"}, {firstName: "", lastName: ""}]

users = users.filter(user => (user.firstName !== '' && user.lastName !== ''));

console.log(users);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead:

```
let users = this.users.filter(user => (user.firstName !== '' && user.lastName !== ''));
```

Comment: You code sample is not using filter.

Comment: @epascarello yeah my bad.